# Fabric: get() when folder contains 2 levels of subfolders fails?

Tags: python, get, fabric

I am fairly new to fabric, so I hope my question is justified ;).
Here it comes: I want to use the get command in order to pull a folder and all files/subfolders from a linux machine to my Win 7 PC with fabric. Each subfolder on its own can also contain subfolders and so on.

Eg:

```
 - main_folder

 --> file1

 --> file2

 -----> subfolder1

 --------> file3

 --------> file4

 -----------> subfolder2

 --------------> file5
```

What I see, is that the get command fails as soon as it sees the subfolder2 ?
Fabric does not really give me a good reason, but I have a feeling that the get does not really work as recursive as I expected it to be :(.
Here is an example when the get fails:

```
 local  path: backups/E1/E1_UPC_CH
 remote path: /opstalj/backup/config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18/

[root@10.199.1.101:22] download: C:\scripts\fab\backups\E1\E1_UPC_CH\config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18\subfolder1\file1.conf <- /opstalj/backup/config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18/subfolder1/file1.conf
[root@10.199.1.101:22] download: C:\scripts\fab\backups\E1\E1_UPC_CH\config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18\subfolder1\file2.conf <- /opstalj/backup/config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18/subfolder1/file2.conf
[root@10.199.1.101:22] download: C:\scripts\fab\backups\E1\E1_UPC_CH\config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18\subfolder1\subfolder2 <- /opstalj/backup/config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18/subfolder1/subfolder2

Fatal error: get() encountered an exception while downloading '/opstalj/backup/config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18/'

Underlying exception:
    Failure
```

As you can see, the get() resulted in the creation of:

- the main folder: config_backup_2014-08-27_09-18
- subfolder1

but aborted when it reached subfolder2 :( ...

I am using the following fabric version:

```
  Fabric 1.9.1
  Paramiko 1.14.0
```

Is it a bug ? Any workaround possible ? Or am I overlooking something ?
Thanks in advance,

Jan

Comment: I also have this problem (Fabric 1.14.0, paramiko 2.3.1, Python 2.7.13, local machine = Windows, remote = RHEL). It does seem like a bug.